# c++ list, no viable conversion from 'value_type'

Tags: c++

I'm using list in c++

```
std::list<Foo> foo;
foo.push_back(bar);
Foo *ret = foo.back();
```

When compile I obtain this error (at last line):

```
No viable conversion from 'value_type' (aka Foo) to 'Foo *'
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.back()` will return a reference (i.e. `Foo &`), but you're trying to assign it to a pointer.

To get it to work, you can assign to a reference instead:

```
Foo &ret = foo.back();
```

Or get the address of the item returned, and assign that to a pointer:

```
Foo *ret = &foo.back();
```

Comment: Reference! I feel so stupid, in documentation I red reference but thought pointer, maybe I should not write code at midnight... thanks...